# How do I make the edge of an element stick to the edge of another element with CSS?

Tags: css

Page here http://jsfiddle.net/d5F2v/1/

I'm trying to make the chat box on the top left's bottom border be stuck to the top border of the text field at the bottom of the page.

Same for the users list box on the top right.

And the right border on the chat should be stuck to the left border of the users box. The way I'm doing it now is defining one's width to be 75% and the other 20%. That's an inconsistent ratio of in between space depending on the resolution of the page.

And if I make the text field's width be 100%, it goes beyond the page. Anyway to tell it to be 100% page width and no more?

Answer (score 0):

if table, try `table{border-collapse:collapse}`

if div, set none border `{border-left:none}`

or using `margin` like this:

```
.c {clear:both;}
.r {float:right;}

.b1 {border:3px solid #123;border-collapse:collapse;margin-left:-3px;}

.b2 {border:3px solid blue;border-collapse:collapse;}


<div class="c">
    <div class="box r b1"></div>
    <div class="box r b2"></div>
<div>
```

Is useful?

Comment: No, this isn't really about 2 elements sharing the same border. It's about making an element's width/height a certain length depending on where another element's border is.